# Opening IE10 in IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I'm wanting a way to open IE 10 in IE8 mode - I can activate it using the F12 dev tools menu after its opened, but ideally I'd like a switch or something so I can open it already in this mode. Is this possible?

Comment: I did a google search and fond an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712259/how-to-make-ie10-default-run-in-ie8-mode-every-time) but you do know the current version of IE isn't IE10 right?

Comment: Yes I do, we're stuck with the corporate version here. I'm lucky, a lot of people are still on IE8!

Answer (score 1):

My First Suggestion would be to move to **Internet Explorer 11**

It has "**Enterprise Mode**" which is like 100% Compatible with Legacy Applications.

(IE 11 Runs as IE8 when run in Enterprise Mode)

For Complete Knowledge of Enterprise Mode : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687.aspx

Comment: Not an option unfortunately, this is a work PC using the version dictated to us by IT!

Comment: I assume you have asked IT for a method to do what you want?

Comment: Since your IE 10 settings are controlled by admin, you can add website url into Compatibility View List, that way IE 10 will run in IE 8. Tools > Compatibility View Settings > Add url and try open website, it should be rendered as Ie 8